# Add id to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. How do I add an id key to them starting from 1.

```
[
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
},
{
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
},
{
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
},
{
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
}
]
```

So, it will be like

```
[
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00",
    id: 1
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0",
    id: 2
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f",
    id: 3
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff",
    id: 4
},
{
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f",
    id: 5 
},
{
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0",
    id: 6
},
{
    color: "black",
    value: "#000",
    id: 7
}
]
```

I tried using `forEach` but it was returning the `id` as the length - 1 value for all the objects inside the array.

I have a large number of objects and can use `lodash` too.

Comment: Can you post how you attempted your forEach loop so we can explain where you went wrong? This will benefit you, and others that come with the same issue, later.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Do you use `var` or `let`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for this. The second argument of the callback refers to the index of the element. So you can assign the ID as `index + 1`.

```js
const source = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
  }
];

source.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = i + 1;
});

console.log(source);
```

Comment: no, you need to use map function

Comment: @malininss why do you think so? Using forEach is perfectly valid in this scenario where OP is just asking to add a key to the objects. Using map is just an overkill.

Comment: Perhaps I was too critical. While forEach is suitable for changing an object's property by reference, the map function is specifically designed for modifying and returning a new array. Using map is more intuitive, but forEach doesn't allocate additional memory for a new array. The main disadvantage of map is the extra memory required for a new object. However, it's generally better to adhere to immutability unless the object has an extra large number of fields and use the map function for these cases.

Answer (score 13):

The simples solution would be to use `map` function

```js
let data = [{ color: "red", value: "#f00" }, { color: "green", value: "#0f0" }]  

data = data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, id: index + 1 }))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over array elements and add `id`:

```
data.forEach((o, i) => o.id = i + 1);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
}, {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
}, {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
}, {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
}, {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
}, {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
}, {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
}];

data.forEach((o, i) => o.id = i + 1);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `map()` function to iterate over your array of objects.

`n` is each of your objects and you can set the `id` value inside the map.

Hope this helps :)

```js
let arr = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
  }
]

let i = 0;
arr.map(n => {
  n['id'] = i;
  i++;
})

  console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  source.map((s, i)=> s.id = i+1); 
   console.log(source)
```

Comment: Please include a textual explanation of how this solves the problem in the question. It is best to void posting "code only" answers.

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to get the required result.

```js
const arr =[{color: "red",value: "#f00"},{color: "green",value: "#0f0"},{color: "blue",value: "#00f"},{color: "cyan",value: "#0ff"},{color: "magenta",value: "#f0f"},{color: "yellow",value: "#ff0"},{color: "black",value: "#000"}];

arr.forEach((o,i)=>o.id=i+1);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

You can also use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr =[{color: "red",value: "#f00"},{color: "green",value: "#0f0"},{color: "blue",value: "#00f"},{color: "cyan",value: "#0ff"},{color: "magenta",value: "#f0f"},{color: "yellow",value: "#ff0"},{color: "black",value: "#000"}];


console.log(arr.map((o,i)=>Object.assign(o,{id:i+1})));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for complex function and logic. Simply loop it over `forEach` which will also give you the index of each object in the array and assign that `index+1` value to the `id` property of the object.

```js
var arr = [
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
},
{
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
},
{
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
},
{
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
}
];

arr.forEach((item, index)=>{
 item.id = index+1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

when i use this solutions my ids get one number
like this:

```
list = [ {
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00",
    id: 0
}, {

    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0",
    id: 4
},{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f",
    id: 4
},{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff",
    id: 4
},{
    color: "black",
    value: "#000",
    id: 4
}]
```

my code is this:

```
let i = 0;
list.map(n => {
        n['id'] = i;
        i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to remove duplicate and `reduce()` to achieve the desired output.

```js
const colorArray = [
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]

const result = colorArray
    .filter((a, i, x) => x.findIndex((t) => t.color === a.color) === i)
    .reduce((agg, item, index) => {
        item.id = index + 1;
        agg.push(item);
        return agg;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```