# create sequence of values in JavaScript array by group

Tags: javascript, foreach

I found this answer on how to map over an array to create ids [Add id to array of objects - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023291/add-id-to-array-of-objects-javascript) for each object in the array, but I was wondering how you'd adapt this code to create a sequence of ids for every group of another value:

```
let dataset = [
 {value: "a"},
 {value: "a"},
 {value: "a"},
 {value: "b"},
 {value: "b"},
 {value: "c"},
]
```

becomes:

```
[
 {value: "a", groupid: 1},
 {value: "a", groupid: 2},
 {value: "a", groupid: 3},
 {value: "b", groupid: 1},
 {value: "b", groupid: 2},
 {value: "c", groupid: 1},
]
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach() method executes a provided function once for each array element, but returns undefined (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). You could use the map() method (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

A working example would be:

```js
let dataset = [{
    value: "a"
  },
  {
    value: "a"
  },
  {
    value: "a"
  },
  {
    value: "b"
  },
  {
    value: "b"
  },
  {
    value: "c"
  },
];

const counterMap = new Map();

let res = dataset.map((val) => {
  const previousGroupId = counterMap.get(val.value);
  let groupId;
  if (previousGroupId === undefined) {
    groupId = 1;
  } else {
    groupId = previousGroupId + 1;
  }
  counterMap.set(val.value, groupId);
  return {
    value: val.value,
    groupId: groupId
  };
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using traditional for loop.

```js
var data = [
 {value: "a"},
 {value: "a"},
 {value: "a"},
 {value: "b"},
 {value: "b"},
 {value: "c"}
]

var id = 1;
var i ;
for(i=0;i<data.length-1;i++){
  var currValue = data[i].value;
  var nextValue = data[i+1].value;
  if(currValue===nextValue){
    id=id+1;
  }
  else {
    id = 1;
  }
    data[i].groupid=id;

}
data[i].groupid=id;
console.log(data);
```