# Extend a Typescript type for object that has a nested object array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023291/add-id-to-array-of-objects) and would like to customize my code in a similar way, except using typescript and a more complicated object.

For example I have the type:

```js
export type ImportationType = {
  commercialImportation: boolean
  dateToManufacturer: string
  barrels: {
    assumedAmount: number
    sealId: string
    uniqueIdentifier?: string
    dateShipped?: string
    dateImported?: string
  }[]
}
```

And now I would like to extend the `barrels` object to have an `id: number` type.

So it would be:

```js
export type UpdatedImportationType = {
  commercialImportation: boolean
  dateToManufacturer: string
  barrels: {
    id: number
    assumedAmount: number
    sealId: string
    uniqueIdentifier?: string
    dateShipped?: string
    dateImported?: string
  }[]
}
```

Currently I'm doing the following:

```js
type UpdatedImportationType: Omit<ImportationType, "barrels"> & {
  barrels: {
    id: number
    assumedAmount: number
    sealId: string
    uniqueIdentifier?: string
    dateShipped?: string
    dateImported?: string
  }[]
}
```

It seems like there should be a better way of adding the `id` field without needing to rewrite the whole type for barrels.

Something like

```js
// Attempt 1
UpdatedImportationType: Omit<ImportationType, "barrels"> & {
  barrels: {
    ...ImportationType["barrels"], // does not work
    id: number
  }[]
}

//Attempt 2
UpdatedImportationType: ImportationType & {
  barrels: {
    id: number
  }[] // creates two `barrels[]` on the type one with id one with all the other fields.
}
```

Can someone show me the Typescript "magic" that I don't yet know to solve this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQb3JN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame It appears to be what I want. Can you add comments explaining the code?

Comment: I see that you've accepted the other answer. Should I write the answer?

Comment: I think your approach was a possible solution, however, it seemed complicated and didn't provide an explanation for what was going on.

Comment: The explanation is provided during the answer, not in the comments. My approach was generic and I thought that was what you were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
type BarrelWithId = ImportationType['barrels'][number] & {id: number}
type WithId = Omit<ImportationType, "barrels"> & {barrels: BarrelWithId[]}
```